# MA57 Installation for Ipopt C++ library (x86_64, Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2)

Tags: ubuntu, c++, optimization

I've been working with Ipopt C++ library optimizer regarding trajectory optimizing tasks. By default the ipopt c++ uses MA27 solver (which is free for usage). I've found out that the best Licensed solver that is easy enough is MA57, I got a license for it as far as I am doing my PhD.

But the problem is that I can't completely understand how to install it and connect to the Ipopt c++ library.

I downloaded MA57 from the [website](https://licences.stfc.ac.uk/product/coin-hsl)

the README file says the following:

```
Legal Notice
============
ALL USAGE OF HSL IS SUBJECT TO LICENCE. PLEASE REFER TO THE FILE 'LICENCE'
DISTRIBUTED WITH THIS SOFTWARE. THIS LICENCE APPLIES TO ALL FILES UNLESS
OTHERWISE INDICATED. IF YOU OBTAINED A COPY OF THIS SOFTWARE WITHOUT THIS FILE,
PLEASE CONTACT HSL@STFC.AC.UK TO OBTAIN ONE.

In particular:
1) You are obliged to cite HSL in any publication or report as:
   "HSL, a collection of Fortran codes for large-scale scientific computation.
    See https://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/"
2) You may not make available to others the software in any form, either as
   source or as a precompiled object.

Introduction
============
Thanks for downloading HSL software. You can find out more information about
HSL by visiting our website: https://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/

This package is intended to be used exclusively with IPOPT. To obtain the full
version of the packages please download them from the HSL web address above.

Installation
============

We now provide binaries for users of some systems. The easiest way to use
CoinHSL is via these which are available from the STFC IP Store
(https://licences.stfc.ac.uk/product/coin-hsl).

These binaries require some additional third party binaries to work. Julia
maintain up to date versions of these for all systems, which we distribute
with our binaries. To update these, just download and unzip the tar.gz file
matching the name of the CoinHSL folder:
- METIS: https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/METIS_jll.jl/releases/latest
- OpenBLAS: https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/OpenBLAS32_jll.jl/releases/latest
- Compiler Support Libraries: https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/CompilerSupportLibraries_jll.jl/releases/latest

To build CoinHSL you will need the Meson (https://mesonbuild.com/) build
system and compilers for both Fortran and C. Libraries for BLAS, LAPACK, and
METIS will also be required.

Once you have these dependencies you can run:

   meson setup builddir --buildtype=release --prefix=$prefix
   meson compile -C builddir
   meson install -C builddir

If Meson fails to detect your BLAS, LAPACK, or METIS, you can define them
explicitly with the following options in the setup call:

    -Dlibblas=$(libblas_liblapack_name)
    -Dliblapack=$(libblas_liblapack_name)
    -Dlibmetis=$(libmetis_name)

If you are unable to use either the binaries or Meson, the installation
instructions provided by IPOPT are based on a different toolchain and may be
of interest.
In particular, you should download the COIN-OR ThirdPary-HSL build system from:
  https://github.com/coin-or-tools/ThirdParty-HSL
please follow the detailed installation instructions given there.

If you opt to build the library yourself, ensure that the library
libcoinhsl.so can be found by both the linker and the dynamic library loader.
We recommend this is done using the `hsllib` option in IPOPT.  Alternatively,
you could either add the path to the ldconfig configuration, or explicitly set
the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Note: IPOPT searches for libhsl.so by default whereas the build tools
      generate libcoinhsl.so. Renaming the file or using the `hsllib` option
      should be sufficient to avoid issues with this.

Other libraries
===============

To use libcoinhsl.so you MUST ensure that:
* Both HSL and IPOPT are compiled with compatible C++ and Fortran compilers,
   for example g++ and gfortran (recommended under linux).
* A BLAS library is available. This library is usually supplied by your
   computer processor vendor (eg Intel MKL), and using a good one is critical
   to performance.
   If you are unable to locate a vendor BLAS then you should use either
   the OpenBLAS or ATLAS BLAS (usually available as part of your linux
   distribution).
   Using the reference BLAS from netlib can often be ten times slower.

It is RECOMMENDED that:
* The METIS matrix ordering routines are available. This can be achieved by
   compiling them as part of IPOPT, see the IPOPT documentation for futher
   details.

Building Windows DLLs
=====================

We make use of cross-compilation to generate the Windows binaries we make
available. As such we have not built CoinHSL on Windows since upgrading our
build system.

If you do choose to build your own DLLs using Meson we would welcome any and
all feedback to hsl@stfc.ac.uk.
```

The problem is that it seems like I'm required to get some "third party binaries"

- METIS: [link](https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/METIS_jll.jl/releases/latest)
- OpenBLAS: [link](https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/OpenBLAS32_jll.jl/releases/latest)
- Compiler Support Libraries: [link](https://github.com/JuliaBinaryWrappers/CompilerSupportLibraries_jll.jl/releases/latest)

I downloaded 3 files:

- CompilerSupportLibraries.v1.1.0.x86_64-linux-gnu-libgfortran5.tar.gz,
- METIS.v5.1.2.x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz,
- OpenBLAS32.v0.3.24.x86_64-linux-gnu-libgfortran5.tar.gz

But the all seem to be working with fortan only.
Or I can use them with C++?

May you please tell me in details how to link the MA57 with Ipopt C++ library?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
What is the question here? Please share only relevant parts of the documentation to make your question concise.